AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'encode'
Estoy realizando un código para comunicación serial entre Python y Arduino, quiero enviar una variable float constantemente que se llama banda con la siguiente linea de código:
serial.Serial().write(banda.encode('utf-8'))

Pero en la terminal me sale el error:
AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'encode'

¿Como podria solucionarlo?

Hola Mónica, bienvenida a [es.so]. El error solo indica que banda es un objeto de tipo Series y que no tiene el método encode, ¿estás usando Pandas? Por el error posiblemente banda sea una serie/columna de dataframe de Pandas.Un float tampoco te sería válido,el método encode() es de las cadenas, es decir banda debe ser una cadena (str) para que esa línea de código funcione. Sin más contexto y sin saber de dónde sale banda poco más vamos a poder ayudar, considera editar la pregunta y agregar algo más de código que muestre de dónde sale banda, a ser posible un [mcve]. Saludos.

Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Hola, no estoy usando Pandas, uso Conda, en especifico site-packages\serial\serialwin32.py, banda es una variable float, debido a que no puedo mandar float mi idea es mandarlo como string y en el programa de arduino convertirlo a float pero me aparece el siguiente error ahora:  raise SerialException("could not open port {!r}: {!r}".format(self.portstr, ctypes.WinError())) serial.serialutil.SerialException: could not open port '5': FileNotFoundError(2, 'The system cannot find the file specified.', None, 2)

@MónicaGonzález ese es otro error. Cómo definiste el puerto? Porque puedes imprimir todos los puertos utilizados. Si está bien definido, estás segura q el baudrate está bien establecido entre el el serial de arduino y el del python? Tienes q descartar varias cosas antes recibir datos. Arduino también lo envía como string, ojo ahí

encode() es un método de la clase str. Si banda no es str, se produce el AttributeError que mencionas:
AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'encode'

Comentas que banda es de tipo float, pero el error indica que estás intentando usar el método encode() desde una objeto de tipo Series.
Si fuera float:
>>> banda = 2/3
>>> banda
0.6666666666666666

>>> banda.encode()
Traceback ...
AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'encode'

Sea del tipo que sea, lo primero es convertir el objeto a un str.
>>> str(banda)
'0.6666666666666666'

Y luego lo puedes convertir a bytes con encode() (que usa 'utf-8' por defecto, así que te puedes ahorrar especificarlo):
>>> str(banda).encode()
b'0.6666666666666666'

Si no te interesen tantos decimales, puedes controlar el formato con un f-string. Por ejemplo, en coma fija con 4 decimales:
>>> f"{banda:.4f}".encode()
b'0.6667'

